# Is it possible to merge cells excluding results with one click?

Tags: notebooks, cells, editing

Now when I merge two cells with right-click "Merge Cells", they merge with the results included, while I only want the commands merged. Can I make it a one-click button?

Now I have to delete the results first then merge.

Comment: Go to `Cell->Delete All Output`, then merge.

Comment: Where do you want the output to go?

Comment: I want to merge the commands and don' t care about the output.

Comment: @xgdgsc "I don't care" is not precise statement. Unless you really meant this, that the output can disappear or not or change the background to Red... Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select just the input cells. <kbd>command</kbd>-click will do this on OS X, but I don't know what the Windows equivalent is. Your selection should look like this

[image: before.png]

Then, with the mouse cursor on one of the blue highlighted cell brackets, right click and select Merge Cells. This produces

[image: after.png]

Comment: It is valid. for windows and linux with `Ctrl+click`. However, I' m usually too lazy to select the small command cell, I usually just select the sequential outer cells with a mouse slide . What I really want is selecting the outer cells and merge without output. Thanks, though.

Comment: @xgdgsc. I can't imagine that what you ask for in your comment is possible. What you describes selects both the input and output cells. How do expect _Mathematica_ to know you don't really mean that? Do you expect it to read your mind?

Comment: @xgdgsc Probably what you want is possible to achieve by creating your own Palette with button which will select inside of the current selection only `Cell`s with the `Input` style and then evaluate `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CellMerge"]]`. It is probably even possible to assign a keyboard shortcuts to this by modifying the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file.